# How to solve the image picker crash app error?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have a app crash when i'm picking a image. i'm using image_picker:0.5.0+7
with any ImageSource it's crash the app.

File _fileState;

```
Future getImage(ImageSource imageSource) async{
  // using your method of getting an image
  final File image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: imageSource);

  print("path:: ");
  setState(() {
   // print("path:: "+image.path);
    _fileState = image;
  });

}
```

> Shutting down VM
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049): Process: com.grain.test_camera, PID: 16049
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity
>   {com.grain.test_camera/com.grain.test_camera.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure deliver
>       ing result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2342, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:25272
>   flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.grain.test
>       _camera/com.grain.test_camera.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received image from picker that was
>   not requested
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3506)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3546)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2795)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
>       E/AndroidRuntime(16049): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2342,
>   result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.provid
>       ers.media.documents/document/image:25272 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.grain.test_camera/com.grain.test_camera.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received image from picke
>       r that was not requested

I do not know what I can do please help me

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to AndroidX compability. You have to [avoid AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#avoiding-androidx) or [migrate your project to AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility#how-to-migrate-a-flutter-app-to-androidx).

There were a breaking change after version [0.5.0](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker#050)

[image]

Comment: I try to downgrade my project and not use androidX but it not work. i still have the error above

Answer (score 0):

`image_picker` plugin does not support `camera permission` condition anymore. For instance, when we try to access camera from an app, the app asks us for permission.
Now, since `image_picker` plugin has removed that condition, we need to ask the permission manually using `permission_handler` plugin. Read more details about this change [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/29422)

Use [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/permission_handler#-readme-tab-) plugin to add the request manually ie runtime and you should be able to get rid of this crash.

Comment: can you please show a example which show how to use Permission?

Comment: Check out this link. It has good example on how to give permission runtime. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNklvY1FEao

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in developer mode, phone close main activity of flutter because of an option in developer options this comment from author of package is

> On Android, the MainActivity can be killed and restarted after launching the image picker for various of reasons. this can be tested by selecting `don't keep activities alive' option in the developer options in phone's setting app.

then when I disable this option I get result in every device that I checked. link of this description is [here](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1512). I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same error
image picker crash on selecting an image

i solved this by using [images_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/images_picker) this will work instead of image_picker

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29960509)

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the IOS simulator.

For anyone having the same problem, I needed to set the permissions messages in Info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to access your photo galery.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs to access your camera.</string>
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems image_picker documentation has been updated.

You would have to use `retrieveLostData` when the app restarts (migrate to AndroidX else you may get a force close error)

```
Future<void> retrieveLostData() async {
    final LostDataResponse response = await ImagePicker.retrieveLostData();
    if (response == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (response.file != null) {
        setState(() {
            if (response.type == RetrieveType.video) {
                _handleVideo(response.file);
            } else {
                _handleImage(response.file);
            }
        });
    } else {
        _handleError(response.exception);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know why this is the accepted answer because this does not actually fix it.

Comment: same here, still don't know why this can help to prevent the crash, for me the line of code after pickImage() function don't even executed before the crash, so after selecting the image the crash is inevitable

Comment: @aswindarma did you all manage to fix? I get the same issue too

Comment: @JohnJoe I did, if you already used the latest version of image_picker and still got the crash problem, it should be image_picker can't work together with some dependencies that you used, for me example, after I delete then re-run 1 by 1 of my other dependencies, finally I found out that image_picker can't work together with image_picker_saver